# How to convert an HTML page (including tables) to PDF using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript

I'm using jspdf for converting jsp(which contains html data) to pdf.The pdf file is generating but all the html data coming at left side.That means i have table,all table cells are displaying at left side,it is not generating exact html data and it is not generating total html page to pdf.I have added all js files to my class path.Will i have to include any other js files.